# How to make the check box true even if it is not ticked in visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to make the check box true even if it is not ticked in visual force page, I mean the picture with tick mark.

but its not working, is ther any other way

**Edit:**

```
<apex:page controller="controller">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton value="New " /></apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Records}" var="R">
            <apex:column headerValue=" Name" value="{!R.name}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="City" value="{!R.City__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Country" value="{!R.Country__c }" />
            <apex:column headerValue="CheckBox" value="{!R.checkbox__c}" />
       </apex:pageBlockTable>...
```

and

```
[class: public with sharing class controller {
      public list < Bank__c > objB = [select id, name, city__c, country__c, CheckBox__c from Bank__c];
       public list < bank__c > getRecords() {
           return objB;
       }
}]
```

Comment: Please provide us with some more information. Are you using <apex:inputfield>? are you using <apex:inputCheckbox>? where does the boolean value need to go, where did it came from? perhaps you can provide us with some code snippets of your VF Page and Extension, this way we can see.

Comment: please provide code snippets

Comment: im retrieving object records in visual force page including a checkbox field when im trying to retrieve checkBox field from object i can see some of them are checked and some are unchecked so i need every thing checked                          <apex:column headerValue="CheckBox" value="!Records.CheckBox__c}"

Comment: can you paste some contoller code .Also makes no sense to show tick all.Is it static tick?

Comment: <apex:page controller="controller" >
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton value="New "/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Records}" var="R" >
              <apex:column headerValue=" Name" value="{!R.name}"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="City" value="{!R.City__c}"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="Country" value="{!R.Country__c }"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="CheckBox" value="{!R.checkbox__c}" />
          </apex:pageBlockTable>

Comment: [class: public with sharing class controller 
{
   public list<Bank__c> objB= [select id,name,city__c,country__c,CheckBox__c from Bank__c ];
    public list<bank__c> getRecords() 
    {
        return objB;
    }
}]

Comment: Rakesh, please update (you can edit it) your question with the things you are trying to post in comments. Comments are deliberately very limited in functionality, because big elaborations are not intended to be placed here. I have done it for you now (needs to be approved).

Do you want to show all chekboxes as true in VF even if they are not true in the object ? Do you want to do this without changing the field values to true, or would setting the field values to tru be the right approach ? Or do you only want to do this after an action is performed on the page ? Please update in ur question.

Comment: If its through backend keep the default value of checkbox true .

Comment: So what do you get in your headerValue="CheckBox" column? Is it blank, a cleared checkbox or something else? Also, you say you want the checkbox checked even if it isn't true. If so, why bother with a dynamic field?

Comment: My thoughts exactly @MikeChale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path to the pictures is

```
/img/checkbox_checked.gif
/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif
```

So you can easily use them in

```
...
<apex:column headerValue="CheckBox">
    <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif" />
    <!-- or maybe <apex:image value="/img/checkbox_{!IF(someCondition,'checked', 'unchecked')}.gif" /> -->
</apex:column>
...
```

You'll have trouble whenever Salesforce decides to move/rename them though. There are several similar questions here already (like [Is there a list of Salesforce images that can be used in custom pages and formula fields?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/is-there-a-list-of-salesforce-images-that-can-be-used-in-custom-pages-and-formul)) that recommend downloading them, packing them up in your own static resource etc.

So "Safe Harbor" and good luck :)

---

EDIT: I think what you need is to tick all the checkboxes server-side? Something like this then:

```
public with sharing class controller {
    public list < Bank__c > objB = [select id, name, city__c, country__c, CheckBox__c from Bank__c];
    public list < bank__c > getRecords() {
        if(objB != null){
            for(Bank__c bank : objB){
                bank.CheckBox__c = true;
            }
        }
        return objB;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code but its not working

Comment: Is it possible to just select "true" in the original SOQL and avoid the loop afterward?

Comment: @MikeChale totally! But I understand he wants to see all records with ticks even if they're not really ticked... Poorly designed question I'd say. Unless you mean field aliasing like in normal SQL? `SELECT true AS Checkbox__c FROM...` kind of thing? Not possible. Only aliasing we can make is in aggregated queries and looks like `SELECT COUNT() countOfAccounts FROM Account`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - that is exactly what I was wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code looks like a  a data issue.Please see the records through query at backend in eclipse or developer console to see if all records have CheckBox__c is true.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the checkboxes selected, I would follow eyescreams solution of iterating through the results in the controller and setting Checkbox__c to true:

```
public with sharing class controller(){
  //change set to public if you want to modify the records in your vf page..
  public List<Bank__c> records {get; private set;}

  public controller(){
    records = 
      [Select 
         Name, 
         City_c, 
         Country_c, 
         Checkbox_c 
       From 
         Bank_c];

    for(Bank__c record : records){
      record.Checkbox__c = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, depending on how you want the checkbox displayed, you can use a nested apex:inputField element, you can use the value attribute of the column (which your code is currently using), or you can use an apex:outputField to show the checkbox. Code for the latter is below:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!records}" var="record">
  <apex:column value="{!record.name}" />
  <apex:column value="{!record.City__c}" />
  <apex:column value="{!record.Country__c }" />
  <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Bank__c.fields.Checkbox__c.label}">
    <apex:outputField value="{!record.Checkbox__c}" />
  </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```