# how to show the images of article ratings and most viewed articles

Tags: apex, visualforce, knowledge

I am currently displaying all the articles based on search results and certain business conditions in a VF page. When displaying the articlelist i am using `<knowledge:articleList>` which is all working fine but i also need to display the article rating and View count for which I am currently querying on KnowledgeArticleVoteStat and KnowledgeArticleViewStat to get the count.

The problem is i am getting the count as integer from this query and need to convert this integer number into a image with the star options as displayed in the standard article page. I also tried articletoolbar option but it works only for article detail page, but i need this in the list view of articles. I just need to convert the integer count to standard sfdc article rating image, can any point me whats the best approach for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have Knowledge available in my org but I suspect the ratings look like star icons on bottom of http://blogforce9dev-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/salesforceicons ?

[image: 3 stars]

If that's the case you can simply take `<img src="/img/samples/stars_300.gif" />` and convert it to `<img src="/img/samples/stars_{!article.KnowledgeArticleVoteStat}00.gif" />`.

I have no idea if range of this int is 0 to 5, sorry. if it can be bigger - just play with scaling it down to thresholds as you see fit, for example `{!MIN(5, CEILING(article.KnowledgeArticleVoteStat / 50))}` (here's the [reference for math functions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?language=en&id=customize_functions.htm) you can use). Whatever logic you might decide is needed & which you can express in formula fields syntax that will end up being a 0-5 number.

---

P.S. There are [some questions here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/is-there-a-list-of-salesforce-images-that-can-be-used-in-custom-pages-and-formul) that warn us that directory structure, filenames etc aren't a "supported API" so Salesforce can change them anytime and then your customization breaks. To play it safe you might decide to upload these images as your own static resource.

Comment: This is excellent .Awesome !Cant believe so cool idea .

Comment: Hi @MohithKumar, thanks :) To be fair it's a well documented thing, except as usual it's "you need to know which keyword to look for", heh. "Advanced formulas examples": https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=useful_advanced_formulas.htm&language=en#ImageFormulasTitle - I guess that's why the files sit in "samples" dir?

Comment: On this page [Stars for Ratings](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=useful_advanced_formulas_image_links.htm&language=en_US) you'll find a formula for rating stars. Go to the section named Stars for Ratings. This should have been a comment on @eyescream's answer, but I can only post this as an answer because of insufficient reputation points!

Answer (score 0):

I always user the raty.js library for this. Just upload the library as a static resource and then you can customize the number of stars you need. You can pass in logic to determine the number of stars or just hard code it.